# I'm getting the following error paragraph ended before gin@iii was complete would please help me

Tags: packages

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{montheoreme}{Théorème}[]
\newtheorem{monlemme}{Lemme}[]
\newtheorem{mondem}{Démonstration}[]
\newtheorem{moncorol}{Corollaire}[]
\newtheorem{mondefin}{Définition}[]
\newtheorem{chapter}{Chapitre}
\newtheorem{monremarq}{Remarque}
\newtheorem{monpropos}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{monexpl}{Exemple}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

\begin{Large}
 \textbf{Biographie :}
\end{Large}
\\

\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{800px-Karl_Weierstrass.jpg} \textbf{Karl Theodor Wilhelm Weierstrass :} habituellement appelé Karl Weierstrass, orthographié Weierstraß en allemand, né le 31 octobre 1815 à Ostenfelde (Westphalie), mort le 19 février 1897 à Berlin, était un mathématicien allemand, lauréat de la médaille Copley en 1895.\\
Il a étudié les mathématiques à l'université de Münster et obtint une chaire à l'Université technique de Berlin. Il fut immobile les trois dernières années de sa vie et s'éteignit à Berlin à la suite d'une pneumonie.\\
Karl Weierstrass est souvent cité comme le « père de l'analyse moderne ». Il consolida des travaux de Cauchy sur les nombres irrationnels et leur amena une nouvelle compréhension. Ses travaux les plus connus portent sur les fonctions elliptiques.
```

Comment: For one, `Large` is not an environment, but a macro `\Large`.

Comment: Changing package `graphics` to `graphicx` would seem to fix the issue.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  Because `graphics` does not support key-value syntax.

Comment: unrelated but the `\\ ` before the includegraphics os wrong (never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph, latex will have warned about that)

Answer (score 3):

In the MWE below, if I employ the package `graphics` rather than `graphicx`, it gives the same `File ended while scanning use of \Gin@iii` error noted by the OP.  Changing `graphics` to `graphicx` solves the problem.

It is because of the use of the keyword-style optional argument (e.g., `scale = ...`), which, as Raoul points out, is not supported by the `graphics` package.  Rather, as David notes in the comment below, the syntax of the optional argument is different for the `graphics` package.

Unless someone tells me otherwise, I would use the `graphics` package for backward compatibility only.  Any new piece of code should employ `graphicx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% gives error if graphics used instead
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}

\includegraphics[scale=.1]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `graphics` version has an optional argument, but with a different syntax. `[3cm,2cm]`